# Javascript - memory usage with incrementing values

Tags: javascript

I am curious about this situation where you use a variable integer that you increment with the javascript increment `++`, and how it affects memory usage. What I am curious about is if the variable is a pointer in the scenario below or if it will add to the stack when incremented using the `++`. Having a hard time finding resources on this, so any input would be helpful.

```
let i = 0;

do {
  i++;
}
while (i < 10);
```

So what I am wondering is with each `++` to the `i` variable, does this impact memory usage?

Comment: I would assume each javascript engine implements this differently. Are you asking generally? or for a specific engine? That way we could have a look at the implementation

Comment: I found this article about v8's object storage. https://www.mattzeunert.com/2017/03/29/v8-object-size.html. It's not strictly about what you're asking, but could give some insight.

Comment: I would say more generally, but if i had to choose and engine - I am using v8 right now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so it will impact memory usage much assuming the variable is small.
Integer needed 4 bytes to be stored. with 4 byte we can store 0 to 4,294,967,295 numbers.
In the case of variable getting incremented more than 4,294,967,295 it will consume more memory than 4 bytes to hold that large value ( like double or long with more memory).

That's my thoughts on it. Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

A variable declaration "let i = 0" will use up the memory intended for a basic type. 32 bits or 64 bits, depending on your underlying architecture. The space in memory is the same for i = 0 all the way up to the max value possible for an integer. So no, incrementing an integer will not change the space that variable takes up in memory.